# Grouping datagrid in silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datagrid

How we can grouping data-grid in silver-light with xaml?
(I used silver-light 4 )

Comment: if u have no answer why hit vote down!

Comment: @For more info: I want to make rows group by one field.for eaxmple by gender

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps somebody wants to give you a hint, that you should provide some additional information so we can get an idea, what your intention is.

Is it a layout question or do you want to group data in a `DataGrid`?

Comment: so if sombody wants to get more info , he should ask :(

Comment: Ah ok. Now I understand the down vote. Google is your friend. The first hit will give you an idea how to achieve your goal.